# Is it possible to set Obsolete attribute to existing method using extension method

Tags: c#

```
My Team use --->     aa.GetItem()       -->> result
```

After create `NewGetItem` extension function. don't use `GetItem`. `GetItem` must be `obsolete`

```
My Team use ---> ┒    aa.GetItem()       ┌ -->> new result
                 │                       │
                 └--> aa.NewGetItem() -->┘
```

i don't have `aa` class code.

How to do it?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you own the module that contains the GetItem() method, you can just [Obsolete] it directly.  If you don't own that module - the scenario is that you want developers to use your new extension method instead of the original method - then you could [make a Code Analysis rule](http://www.bing.com/search?q=writing+a+code+analysis+rule) that fails if it detects a call to that method.  That way, when your developers run Code Analysis against the project, you can  direct them to the appropriate new extension method.

Answer (score 1):

No, the attribute should be applied directly to the method you want to mark as obsolete.